scipy smoothening issue with zero values in window
I have a pandas dataframe like this:
1960-09-01  24027064    4503904.333
1960-10-01  18020298    3377928.25
1960-11-01  12013532    2251952.167
1960-12-01  6006766     1125976.083
1961-01-01  0   0
1961-02-01  0   0
1961-03-01  0   0
1961-04-01  0   0
1961-05-01  0   0
1961-06-01  0   0
1961-07-01  0   0
1961-08-01  0   0
1961-09-01  0   0
1961-10-01  0   0
1961-11-01  0   0
1961-12-01  0   0
1969-01-01  0   0
1969-02-01  6173432.667 1150976.083
1969-03-01  12346865.33 2301952.167
1969-04-01  18520298    3452928.25

I am trying to smoothen the data using somthing like this:
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
df = df.apply(savgol_filter, window_length=df.shape[0] // 5, polyorder=2)

I am getting something like this:
1960-09-01  25874679.88 4850242.328
1960-10-01  24574614.17 4606543.324
1960-11-01  23301520.97 4367900.35
1960-12-01  22055400.26 4134313.405
1961-01-01  20836252.04 3905782.489
1961-02-01  19644076.31 3682307.603
1961-03-01  18478873.09 3463888.745
1961-04-01  17340642.35 3250525.916
1961-05-01  16229384.11 3042219.117
1961-06-01  15145098.37 2838968.347
1961-07-01  14087785.12 2640773.605
1961-08-01  13057444.36 2447634.893
1961-09-01  12054076.1  2259552.21
1961-10-01  11077680.33 2076525.557
1961-11-01  10128257.06 1898554.932
1961-12-01  9205806.28  1725640.336
1969-01-01  19071395.37 5088684.927
1969-02-01  19448311.7  5412158.942
1969-03-01  19790962.91 5737508.936
1969-04-01  20099349    6080752.937

But I dont want it that way, I want to keep zeros as zeros and also while computing smoothening function I want to ignore the zeros and apply smoothing function to the rest elements in the sliding window. For example if my window_length is 5 and I have [0, 0, 6173432.667, 12346865.33, 18520298] as current window content, I want the smoothening function to drop the zeros and convert the window to size of 3 ie [6173432.667,12346865.33,18520298] and calculate accordingly. In other words, essentially I want to apply piece-wise curve fitting for each of the non-zero stretch as smoothening function.

You could try using pandas rolling and apply a custom function with different numbers of savgol_coeffs depending on the data. However, I'm unsure if using different coefficients for this type of filtering makes sense.

When you apply the convolve1d function (it is inside savgol_filter, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.14.1/scipy/signal/_savitzky_golay.py#L351) it already works like you have described: zero values adds nothing to result of convolution.
You can just save a mask with current positions of zeros and make same places in final result zeros again.
zero_mask = values == 0
values = values.apply(
    savgol_filter, 
    window_length=values.shape[0] // 5, 
    polyorder=2
)
values[zero_mask] = 0



Or, you can apply savgol_filter directly to non-zero values, if you want the result looks like there are no zeros at all:
values.loc[~zero_mask] = values.loc[~zero_mask].apply(
    savgol_filter, 
    window_length=values.shape[0] // 5, 
    polyorder=2
)

